# Is there a way to import video names from a YouTube playlist into a Google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, youtube, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to set up a rudimentary program that accesses all videos in a playlist and lists them in a google sheet using `IMPORTHTML`. However, it only loads 100 videos out of the 214 videos that are in the playlist. Is there a way to get all of the other 114 videos to appear in the list when I use the `IMPORTHTML`?

I have tried using `IMPORTFEED`, but the RSS feed for the playlist is outdated. I do not know how to use `IMPORTXML`, which limits my use of `IMPORTXML` to basic functions. `IMPORTDATA` only gives me hyperlinks, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I just started making this program 1 hour ago. I believe I am using the lastest version of google sheets

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this is to create a 2nd spreadsheet where you will put videos from 101-200 and then you will use `IMPORTRANGE` to import the whole array of names at once. not so sophisticated solution but works on 100%